# why isn't fwrite overwriting my data in wb+?

Tags: c, binary

I wrote a small program in C that creates a list of students in a binary file.  I call function `fsearch()` (below) to search for a specified student and change his data, but the data seems not to be modified.

```
// the file is opened in mode "wb+"
int fsearch(FILE *f)
{
    student s;
    float matsearch;
    printf("enter the matricule you want to find ");
    scanf("%f",&matsearch);
    rewind(f); // starting the search from the beginning
    while(fread(&s,sizeof(student),1,f)==1 && s.mat!=matsearch);
    if(s.mat==matsearch)
    {
        printf("we found what searched for\n");
        printf("name: %s\n",s.fname);
        printf("last name: %s\n",s.lname);
        printf("matricule: %.f\n",s.mat);
        fseek(f,-sizeof(student),SEEK_CUR);     
        student a;
        scanf("%s",&(a.fname));
        scanf("%s",&(a.lname));
        scanf("%d",&(a.mat));
        if(fwrite(&a,sizeof(student),1,f)==1)
        {
             printf("successfully wrote");  // this message does get printed
        }
        return(1); // successfully found
    }

    printf("we didn't find what you searched for\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Fyi, `scanf("%d",&(a.mat));` smells funny. If the `mat` member is an `int` this is right, but I question the `float` type of `matsearch`; if `a.mat` is `float`, then the `%d` format specifier for `scanf` is wrong. Since you chose not to post what a `student` actually *is*, only you know for sure.

Comment: yeah you're right :p careless mistake (thank you) but what about the fwrite issue ?

Comment: Are you looking for the change by reading the file again later in the same program, or independently?  If the latter, then do you wait until the program finishes, closes the file, or at least flushes it?

Comment: looking for the change by reading the file in the same programe

Comment: Supposing that `student.fname` and `student.lname` are `char` arrays (not pointers) I don't see anything wrong with the code presented, other than the field descriptor problem already mentioned.  I'm inclined to suspect, therefore, that the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: thank's anyway i really appreciate it

Comment: the scanf() calls to acquire the new values from the user: 1) need to check the returned value from each call (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) the fields; fname and lname are most likely char arrays.  so should not need the '&' for those two fields because using the name of an array degrades to the address of the first character in the array.  3) it might help the debug to print the values obtained via scanf()

Comment: the code should check the returned value from fseek() to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding this line: 'while(fread(&s,sizeof(student),1,f)==1 && s.mat!=matsearch);'  if the read fails, due to an error or EOF, then nothing (new) has been placed in the s.mat field.  suggest not comparing the contents of the s.mat field until after checking the results of the fread.  Which implies that the returned value from fread() needs to be keep in a variable so it can be checked after exiting the while loop

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the one posted by bluesawdust, I found some other mistakes in the code:

- `// the file is opened in mode "wb+"`: this means that your file was destroyed on open (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/)). You might want to use `"rb+"`
- since you didn't initialize your `student s` structure (and no record was ever written in it because of my previous point) `s.mat` contains a random value
- `scanf("%d",&(a.mat));`: as for `printf`, you should change the format string to `"%f"` (but actually you should use a string type, comparing `float`s with `==` is not good practice because of the roundings)

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(student)` is unsigned, so negating it is not appropriate here. You should cast it to an `int` before negating.

Comment: point taken. but i don't think that this is the cause of problem because when i created my file and put data in it for the first time using the same "fwrite" it worked like a charm

Comment: You wouldn't have used fseek the first time you wrote.